# Volume control applet disappeared

Tags: xubuntu, applet

I've just installed Xubuntu 13.10, played around with it to customize the GUI. I somehow lost the volume control applet from the notification area. How can I get it back? I've already clicked through all preferences menus I could find.

BTW: Why is this applet part of a notification area?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xfce4-mixer is the front-end for mixer settings delivered together with the Xfce4 desktop environment. It does the same jobs other mixer front-ends do, but is integrated into the Xfce4 desktop as a plugin for the Xfce4 main panel. To install xfce4-mixer from the terminal in Ubuntu 12.04-14.04 run:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer
```

Right-click on the panel and choose *Panel* -> *Add New Items*. From the **Add New Items** window, add the Audio Mixer applet, or drag the Audio Mixer applet icon from the Add New Items window to the panel.

There isn't a Sound icon in Xubuntu 13.10 Settings Manager, so if you want to change the sound settings, you have to right-click the Audio Mixer applet icon in the panel, and change the sound settings from there.

Comment: Works well. I cannot understand why xfc4-mixer is not part of basic Xubuntu...

Comment: Could not figure out what it was called when I lost it during my upgrade from Fedora 22 to 24. I could not find how to change which device was being used by the PluseAudio applet, whereas that dropdown the main property of the XFCE Audio Mixer.

Comment: In 16.04+ xfce4-mixer has been discontinued and it has not been replaced, but it has instead been superseded by a different package called xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the Whisker menu under multimedia as Pulse Volume Control or something like that and right clicked and selected 'add to panel.'